# Place snackbar in a Utility class

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am using this method quite a lot to display snackbar messages with the colors used in the app.  For this reason I wanted to make the method static and place it in a final class of utilities, so I can use it all over the place and no repeat it everytime.

However, this has the problem that `findViewById` and `getResources().getColor` etc.. need an activity to "live in" and cannot be static either.

Any elegant way to do this?  I have been looking in the other posts but none of them did quite reflect this issue.
Thanks!!

```
    protected void displaySnackbar (String s)
{
    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View sbview = snack.getView();
    sbview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_light));
    snack.show();
}
```

Comment: The root view of the Snackbar can be different from `android.R.id.content` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your inspiration.. this code works now:

```
    protected static void sacaSnackbar (Context context, View view, String s)
{
    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View sbview = snack.getView();
    sbview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(contexto, R.color.colorAccent));
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_light));
    snack.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this method where you want show the snackbar and pass the respective parameter in that class

```
protected void displaySnackbar (View view,String s)
    {
        Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        View sbview = snack.getView();
        sbview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
        TextView textView = (TextView) sbview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_light));
        snack.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code [gist](https://gist.github.com/devrath/26a182559a643fc5085b)

posting code in case link goes down

```
public class UtilSnackbar {
    /************************************ ShowSnackbar with message, KeepItDisplayedOnScreen for few seconds*****************************/
    public static void showSnakbarTypeOne(View rootView, String mMessage) {
        Snackbar.make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null)
                .show();
    }

    /************************************ ShowSnackbar with message, KeepItDisplayedOnScreen*****************************/
    public static void showSnakbarTypeTwo(View rootView, String mMessage) {

        Snackbar.make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("Action", null)
                .show();

    }

    /************************************ ShowSnackbar without message, KeepItDisplayedOnScreen, OnClickOfOk restrat the activity*****************************/
    public static void showSnakbarTypeThree(View rootView, final Activity activity) {

        Snackbar
                .make(rootView, "NoInternetConnectivity", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("TryAgain", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
                        activity.finish();
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setActionTextColor(Color.CYAN)
                .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                        super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
                        super.onShown(snackbar);
                    }
                })
                .show();

    }

    /************************************ ShowSnackbar with message, KeepItDisplayedOnScreen, OnClickOfOk restrat the activity*****************************/
    public static void showSnakbarTypeFour(View rootView, final Activity activity, String mMessage) {

        Snackbar
                .make(rootView, mMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction("TryAgain", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
                        activity.finish();
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                })
                .setActionTextColor(Color.CYAN)
                .setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                        super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
                        super.onShown(snackbar);
                    }
                })
                .show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the view and context as parameter for the method

```
    protected void displaySnackbar (Context context, View view, String s)
 {
    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view, s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View sbview = snack.getView();
    sbview.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_light));
    snack.show();
}
```

Comment: Problem with that is:  "this" must be changed to "context", so ok there, and the other thing is that  when we add context to the line "context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_light)" , getColor() appears as deprecated

Comment: @JaviMar maybe you should pass ContextCompat as an extra param to the function because getColor method prompts for context

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Context and View as a parameter

```
protected static void displaySnackbar (View view, Context context,String s) {
 Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(view.findViewById(android.R.id.content), s, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    View sbview = snack.getView();
    sbview.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbview.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_light));
    snack.show();
}
```